# How to troubleshoot CSS applied by JavaScript using FireBug

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

I am using JavaScript to add some content to my page.  It is not displayed on the screen, and I used the FireBug HTML tab to investigate what style is being applied to the element, and I see the following:

```
element.style {display: list-item;opacity: 0;}
```

Okay, that is why it is not being displayed.  There is no CSS filename to the right in the FireBug console, so the style must have been applied by JavaScript.  How can I determine what script is adding this style to the element?

Thank you

Comment: Chrome has a very good "inspect" feature that I like more than firebug.  IMO It is a little more comprehensive and explicit in telling you this sort of thing.

Comment: you will have to track it in your js files.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check out Chrome.  How do I track it in my JS files?

Comment: Just installed Chrome.  Shows the same style for the element, but does not specify what set the style.

Comment: You can trak your easily JS files pressing Control+U in order to view source and then Control+F to search. You can search "list-item" or/and "opacity", but avoid searching "0" and "display" because they are very common. Or you could download the files and use a program which searches inside all your JS files at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Oriol,  Yea tried that first.  Nothing in the main HTML file. I also then systematically removed any JavaScript included by the main file, but where do you stop?

Comment: How are you adding the HTML to the DOM? Do you have any plugins installed (like a carousel) that would effect list items (li's)?

Comment: I am adding the to the DOM using http://codecanyon.net/item/news-widget/discussion/98025.  What's funny is that I do it at two places on the same page, and...  Let me check...  Ha ha, turned out I was using the same ID twice.